# Mongodb aplicar $cond sólo a determinados documentos de una colección

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección con dos tipos de documentos:

```
{ "_id" : "G", "name" : "Galway", "pop" : 258058 }
{ "_id" : 3, "car" : { "reg" : "142-G-28", "engineSize" : 1 }, "addresses" : [ "MO", "G", "WH" ] }
```

y quiero aplicar esta consulta

```
db.docs.aggregate([{
         $project:
           {item: 1,
             pop:{
                 $cond: { if: { $gte: [ '$pop', 100000 ] }, then: 'Big county', else: 'Small county'}}}}])
```

pero sólo a los documentos que tienen el atributo 'pop'

He intentado poner un `{pop: {$exists: "true"}` pero no funciona. Tal vez añadir un `$lookup` o algo?

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes, sucede que el operador `$exists` no lo puedes usar directamente en un proceso de agregación como lo estabas intentando. Puedes consultar los operadores de agregación en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

La solución es usar un [`stage`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) previo usando [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match), que realiza un filtro de acuerdo a una condición establecida.

En este caso deseas filtrar los documentos en los cuales exista el campo `pop`, por lo tanto puedes escribir la condición de la siguiente manera:

```
{$match: {pop: {$exists: true}}}
```

Como puedes apreciar, la condición `{pop: {$exists: true}}` le indicará a Mongo que sólo permita los documentos coincidentes (*match*) con la condición: **existe el campo `pop`**.

Luego puedes pasar tu segundo `stage` de la agregación que era el que ya tenías escrito, de esta forma los documentos que serán analizados en el segundo `stage` serán aquellos que posean el campo `pop`.

El proceso de `aggregate` quedaría así:

```
db.docs.aggregate([
  {$match: {pop: {$exists: true}}}, // <- el primer stage filtra los documentos
  {$project: 
    {item: 1, pop:
      {$cond: 
        {
          if: {$gte: ['$pop', 100000]},
          then: 'Big County',
          else: 'Small County'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

De esta forma el proceso de agregación se realizará tal como lo deseas.

Una captura del resultado usando tus datos como ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo de $match en aggregation MongoDB]

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu duda.

Answer (score -1):

solo sería necesario una consulta simple

```
db.docs.find({"pop":{$gte:100000}})
```

> *{ "_id" : "G", "name" : "Galway", "pop" : 258058 }*

ahora, si quieres sacar solo algunos de los campos del documento

```
db.docs.find({"pop":{$gte:100000}},{"_id":0, "name":1})
```

> *{"name" : "Galway"}*

el *"_id":0* lo exime de la extracción, *"name":1* lo trae

Comment: Esta no es la operación que desea realizar el OP. Hay una diferencia muy grande entre [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) y [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). Saludos